# Android: How to set a textview's text size based on another text view programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, textview

So I have two text views, one a that has a specific height and auto-size properties implemented in it. The other is a normal multiple lined text view with wrap content as height.

```
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMovieRating"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/tvOthersActivityMovieHeight"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/text_view_movie_description_margin_start"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/mainCLMarginActivityMovie"
            android:text="@string/movieRatingHint"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="@dimen/all_auto_max_text_sizes"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="@dimen/all_auto_min_text_sizes"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="@dimen/all_auto_size_step_granularities"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvMovieNameAndDate"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMovieDescriptionList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/text_view_movie_description_margin_start"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/mainCLMarginActivityMovie"
            android:textSize="268sp"
            android:text="@string/lorem_ispum"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvNonChangeableDescriptionText"
            />
```

Now what I'm trying to set the 2nd textView's textSize size based on the first textView's textSize.
I've tried:

```
binding.tvMovieDescriptionList.textSize = binding.tvMovieRating.textSize
```

but it didn't work, any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly do the following: `setTextSize(getTextSize())`.

The reason is the `getTextSize()` is returning the **exact pixel size**, meanwhile `setTextSize()` sets the **scaled pixel unit**. The unit does not align with these functions.

So for the simplest way, you can mention the unit when you are setting the size:

```kotlin
binding.tvMovieDescriptionList.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, binding.tvMovieRating.textSize)
```

Or you can calculate the scaled pixel unit yourself before setting:

```kotlin
val metrics = resources.displayMetrics
binding.tvMovieDescriptionList.textSize = binding.tvMovieRating.textSize / metrics.density
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you've forgotten to notify your binding. Most changes in bindings require you to notify them to update them. I would try

```
binding.notify()
```

or

```
binding.notifyAll()
```

On another note, you could always simply copy your auto-sizing dimensions over to your secondary text view. I don't see why you couldn't do that, as this is only two text views, not 1120.

Comment: Because the second text view isn't one line, so I can't specify a specific height

Comment: and it the binding does get notified, but the second text view always ends up with larger text si ze